# How to sent broadcast From App A to App B

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm practicing sending custom broadcast from one app (App A) to another app (App B), but App B seems not receving the broadcast, though I had tried both manifest-declared and context-registered methods. My emulator is API 24. Where was I wrong?

Broadcast sending from App A:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val TAG = "TestingApp2: MainActivity"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        binding.btnSend.setOnClickListener{
            Intent().also{
                intent.setAction("duke.deviluke.testingapp2.CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME")
                intent.putExtra("data", "broadcast from app A")
                sendBroadcast(intent)
                Log.d(TAG, "Broadcast sent: " + intent.action)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Receiver in App B:

My BroadcastReceiver:

```
class CustomBroadcast: BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive()" + intent?.action)
        StringBuilder().apply {
            append("Action: ${intent?.action}\n")
            append("Extra: ${intent?.extras.toString()}")
            toString().also {
                Log.d(TAG, it)
                Toast.makeText(context, it, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In Manifest:

```
<receiver android:name=".CustomBroadcast"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="duke.deviluke.testingapp2.CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME"/>
            </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In code:

```
private val CUSTOM_BROADCAST = "duke.deviluke.testingapp2.CAN_YOU_HEAR_ME"

// custom br
private val br2: BroadcastReceiver = CustomBroadcast()
private val filter2 = IntentFilter(CUSTOM_BROADCAST)
private val listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps2 = true
private val receiverFlags2 = if (listenToBroadcastsFromOtherApps2) {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_EXPORTED
    } else {
        ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED
    }

private fun registerCustomReceiver() {
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(baseContext, br2, filter2, receiverFlags2)
}

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate()")
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_context)

        val binding = ActivityContextBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        registerCustomReceiver()
}
```

With normal broadcast from system, I'm receiving it well from both above method. But the custom broadcast was not received by the App B.

Comment: Your code is using implicit `Intent` objects, and broadcasts of those [have been banned for six years](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/04/11/android-o-implicit-broadcast-ban.html).

Comment: I don't think that would work in my case since it's only for the [system events](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcast-exceptions). But I've figured it out since I'm using the lambda inside the Intent.also{} in the sending part, so the **intent** param should be replaced with **it** param. But thanks for the advice :D

Comment: A little edit for my above comment. Yes, your advice is correct, but the emulator I'm using is API 24, which is below Android Oreo, so the manifest declared/implicit Intent is still working :D

Answer (score 1):

permission should be defined in Manifest file .
Also need to add ComponentName in Sender Activity.